# Using font awesome with media queries

Tags: html, css

Am developing a website using media queries and have a struggle to use font awesome.
Below is my code in html where I attempted to add a font to a span tag but nothing happens.

```
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;+1.88.222.5674</span>
```

How can I turn this around?

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: is there any blank boxes on the place of icons??

Comment: sorry I forgot to send the link. Is exactly the way Minal did but it does not work.
https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/z1boe3xo/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this:

Add font-awesome css link into your header part.

```
<span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;+1.88.222.5674</span>
```

Here is jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/qwezyrqj/

Comment: I actually did it the same way but mine does not work for some reason.
https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/z1boe3xo/

Comment: Please check my link: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/z1boe3xo/.

It is actually the same way you did but mine does not work.
Did not see the link in your jsfiddle.

Comment: you have to import the font. Look in the left of @Minal Chauan 's fiddle "External resources" section has a css with the awesome font

Comment: I has import font awesome font external link in "External resources" in jsfiddle.